# Why is Gatling pausing to send Requests

Tags: performance, scala, gatling

I just wanted to create a simple scenario (with Gatling 2.1.7) which ramps up 100 users and requests URL´s from a given url.csv for 1800 seconds in the fastest possible way. At the first look everything seems to work fine but after ~3200, ~6400, ~9600 (...) number of requests it looks to me Gatling is just pausing for a minute or more.

Scala:

```
class stress_ScanWebpagesViaCSV extends Simulation {
  val url = csv("url.csv").circular;
  val users: Int = 100;
  val secondsToRun: Int = 1800;
  val scn = scenario("Test URL´s from CSV").during(secondsToRun seconds) {
    feed(url).exec(
      http("${urls}")
        .get("${urls}")
        .check(status.is(200))
    )
  }
  setUp(scn.inject(rampUsers(users) over (20 seconds)).disablePauses);
```

Console:

```
================================================================================
2015-12-18 12:34:12                                          35s elapsed
---- Test URL´s from CSV ------------------------------------------------------
[--------------------------------------------------------------------------]  0%
          waiting: 0      / active: 100    / done:0
---- Requests ------------------------------------------------------------------
> Global                                                   (OK=2583   KO=0     )
...
================================================================================


================================================================================
2015-12-18 12:34:17                                          40s elapsed
---- Test URL´s from CSV ------------------------------------------------------
[--------------------------------------------------------------------------]  0%
          waiting: 0      / active: 100    / done:0
---- Requests ------------------------------------------------------------------
> Global                                                   (OK=3199   KO=0     )
...
================================================================================


================================================================================
2015-12-18 12:34:22                                          45s elapsed
---- Test URL´s from CSV ------------------------------------------------------
[--------------------------------------------------------------------------]  0%
          waiting: 0      / active: 100    / done:0
---- Requests ------------------------------------------------------------------
> Global                                                   (OK=3199   KO=0     )
...
================================================================================


================================================================================
2015-12-18 12:34:27                                          50s elapsed
---- Test URL´s from CSV ------------------------------------------------------
[--------------------------------------------------------------------------]  0%
          waiting: 0      / active: 100    / done:0
---- Requests ------------------------------------------------------------------
> Global                                                   (OK=3199   KO=0     )
...
================================================================================


================================================================================
2015-12-18 12:34:32                                          55s elapsed
---- Test URL´s from CSV ------------------------------------------------------
[--------------------------------------------------------------------------]  0%
          waiting: 0      / active: 100    / done:0
---- Requests ------------------------------------------------------------------
> Global                                                   (OK=3199   KO=0     )
...
================================================================================


================================================================================
2015-12-18 12:34:37                                          60s elapsed
---- Test URL´s from CSV ------------------------------------------------------
[--------------------------------------------------------------------------]  0%
          waiting: 0      / active: 100    / done:0
---- Requests ------------------------------------------------------------------
> Global                                                   (OK=3199   KO=0     )
...
================================================================================
```

I got 32 URL´s in my csv File. My guess is that every User requests the Sites one time and then pauses. How to fix this ?

Answer (score 2):

You're probably saturating ephemeral ports.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That was also my first guess. Afterwards i ran the Test under the same circumstances with 50 Users. This time Gatling paused after ~1600 Requests. It seems to me every User makes 32 Requests and then pauses.

Comment: ~1600 is the default ephemeral port range size on OSX.